# SpringApplication in docker doesn't work anymore

Tags: java, spring, docker

i have a strange problem. I have created a spring application with some functional logic and started it locally - it worked.
Then i have exported my whole project to a .war file and build a docker image to run it also locally - it worked.

Since ca. 2 day...i guess i did some changes...i want to build and run my docker file again, but stops always at this point:

```
    Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 17.0.0.2/wlp-1.0.17.cl170220170523-1818) on IBM J9 VM, version pxa6480sr4fp10-20170727_01 (SR4 FP10) (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/17.0.0.2/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0093A: Processing configuration drop-ins resource: /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/configDropins/defaults/keystore.xml
[WARNING ] CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID com.ibm.ws.security.registry.basic.config[basic].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS4104A: LTPA keys created in 6.228 seconds. LTPA key file: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/ltpa.keys
[AUDIT   ] CWPKI0803A: SSL certificate created in 8.761 seconds. SSL key file: /opt/ibm/wlp/output/defaultServer/resources/security/key.jks
[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://2b88d6a3093b:9080/xxxxxx/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application xxxxx started in 1.828 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, wasJmsServer-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, javaMail-1.5, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jpa-2.1, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, jsonp-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, jpaContainer-2.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
[AUDIT   ] 

CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

My Spring application doesn't start anymore. In general it would continue with this:

```
    2017-10-05 13:34:46.723  INFO 11136 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@c3c60d: startup date [Thu Oct 05 13:34:46 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-05 13:34:47.070  INFO 11136 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-10-05 13:34:47.112  INFO 11136 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$240b40b3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)
........
```

If i start my application locally from eclipse, it still works without any problems, but of course i want to build the docker image again.

Where do i have to search, if the SpringApplication start locally from the environment, but not from the docker images/container. Here it stops at 
"The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet."

Thank you in adnvance!

-----------------  UPDATE -----------------

I found something. My exported .war file has just a size of 134kb. I am sure, it was ca. 35mb before. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Can you provide your tried code in details with POM.

Comment: How do you build the artifact? Do you start it as a jar, or you deploy a war to a running server? If it is a war, did you exclude embedded server from the dependencies? What docker image are you using (depending on artifact type you might need different)? Did you try to start the app locally from command line?

Comment: Sounds like you don't use a version control system - I suggest you do that next time.

Comment: SamDev:  i will add it tomorrow 
@OleksandrShpota it's a maven project. But i do right-click on the project, export, export as .war file. Then copy this to my local redHead environment, build the .war file with "docker build xxxxxx ." and can see my created docker image. With "docker run -p ...." i start the application. Or what do you mean? What do you think, does it have something to do with the .pom, the code or what else?

Henry: i am using a version control system, but can't find anything

Comment: If you're using version control, why can't you just roll back to the working version?

Comment: because i changed and add a lot of the logic code. But if the problem is to find in the .pom or somewhere else, i can specially have a look there.

Comment: I found maybe a hint. If i export my .war file, the size is now just 350kb. I think it was ca. 70mb before.